# Child class cannot use subtype property in place of the parent class property

Tags: typescript

Okay strange title, not sure how else to put it. 
So this is the problem.
I was under the impression that if I pass in the subtype of the parent constructor property, to the child constructor property everything will work. However, that is not the case. If I try to use the subtype method on the child property I get an error.

```js
interface IDataMaper{
    save():void
}

interface IReactiveDataMapper extends IDataMaper{
    saveReactive():void
}


class A {
    constructor(protected mapper: IDataMaper) {}
}

class B extends A {

    constructor(mapper: IReactiveDataMapper) {
        super(mapper)//no errror here
        // this.mapper.saveReactive() //error
    }
}
```

[Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=2&module=5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE5jgWTgB2gG8AoZc5AZzgDcIAKASgC4aB7YAExIF8STQkWIhSoAShERhgdTNjz5CUZBAAekEJ0po5uAsTIVqdCVJkMW7Lr34kEAGziVtAQWSkKyBGxCUwUAFcEMDYoenwoNkhgiE5kAFsCJWYdLD0lRnc+PgcnbQAhFXUITVd3Q3IKrx8-QODQ+kTFaBTxSWDzXQUM8s9PSgClRqToTIB6MZA2FShI5QALaAgqzwnkMHngSgA6JqVt4whTDromZAnoOarsilsgA)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are accessing the `mapper` instance from the `this` context. Note the `protected mapper: IDataMapper` in the constructor of class A. By prepending the keyword `protected` there, you enforce that the class A will have a protected member called `mapper` of the type `IDataMapper`. In the constructor of B, you do not have the keyword `protected`, meaning that the protected member `mapper` of B's `this`-context is not overwritten, and the `IDataMapper`-property stored by A is used. Add a `protected`-prefix to the variable in B's constructor to have it overwrite the member and you will not experience the error.

```
interface IDataMaper{
    save():void
}

interface IReactiveDataMapper extends IDataMaper{
    saveReactive():void
}


class A {
    constructor(protected mapper: IDataMaper) {}
}

class B extends A {

    constructor(protected mapper: IReactiveDataMapper) {
        super(mapper);
        this.mapper.saveReactive();
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=2&module=5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE5jgWTgB2gG8AoZc5AZzgDcIAKASgC4aB7YAExIF8STQkWIhSoAShERhgdTNjz5CUZBAAekEJ0po5uAsTIVqdCVJkMW7Lr34kEAGziVtAQWSkKyBGxCUwUAFcEMDYoenwoNkhgiE5kAFsCJWYdLD0lRnc+PgcnbQAhFXUITVd3Q3IKrx8-QODQ8MjoyDjExWgU8Ulg810FDPLPT0oApXo2jKrPMAALYEoAOgnoBeMIUx66JirsilsgA)

Comment: Actually that is how I did it at first, but if you look at the generated code of the 'B' class constructor, 'mapper' property is being immediately reassigned which competently overwrites the property in the parent class and any initialization of that property done there.

Comment: Well, yes, but in B's constructor you are accessing the ``this.mapper`` property, so you have the two options given as answers, either overwrite ``this.mapper`` in the subclass B or, as @kaya3 suggested, don't access ``this.mapper`` but ``mapper`` directly. Otherwise I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't understand why the code from the demo shows an error. Since `mapper` is a subtype it is guaranteed to have everything that the `parent` type has. As stated before I need to access `mapper` in other methods of the class so I need `this.mapper`

Answer (score 0):

Lukas's answer gives a good explanation of why this error occurs; the type of `this.mapper` is `IDataMapper`, not the more specific type `IReactiveDataMapper`.

As an alternative solution which doesn't require changing the type of the field or declaring a new field with a different type, you can call the method on the parameter `mapper`, which references the same object as `this.mapper` but has the more specific type:

```js
class B extends A {
    constructor(mapper: IReactiveDataMapper) {
        super(mapper);
        mapper.saveReactive(); // instead of this.mapper
    }
}
```

This option may be simpler if you only need the more specific type in the constructor, as in your example. If you need `this.mapper` to have the more specific type in other methods in the subclass, then Lukas's answer is the best way.

Comment: I need to access the 'mapper' property from other methods of the class also.